# Firebase custom query

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get the value of Inmate_DOB from the below structure of Firebase Web API.

Please find the snap below :

[image: Firebase Dashboard - Realtime DB]

I tried the below code is it right to handle, But I didn't retrieve the value.

> GetInmate.Js

```
angular.module('starter.InMateIdContactDetailsController', ['firebase'])

.controller('InMateIdContactDetailsCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,$filter,$ionicLoading,$state,$window, $cordovaSQLite,$cordovaCamera,$firebase,$firebaseAuth,$firebaseArray) {

var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("Tables/Inmate_Data");

$scope.InMatedata = $firebaseArray(ref);

if(!$scope.InMatedata){

alert('Records not found Auth!');

}else{

alert('Records found! Auth');

}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

if(user) {
var userID = user.uid;

firebase.database().ref('Tables/Inmate_Data/'+userID).once('value').then(snapshot => {
const userDOB = snapshot.val().Inmate_DOB;
alert(userDOB);
alert(test);
})
}
});



});
```

Comment: get values instead of  give a static key

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just missing a `/` in your original code after `'Tables/Inmate_Data'`.

```
return firebase.database().ref('Tables/Inmate_Data/' + userId).once('value')
.then(function(snapshot) {
      var Inmate_dob = snapshot.val().Inmate_DOB;
      alert(Inmate_dob);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`, you might want to use `onAuthStateChanged()`, this way you can always be sure that the code inside the block will only be executed if the user is actually logged in otherwise `firebase.auth().currentUser` might return null. If you have made sure that this value is not null, then you can do something like this:

```
var userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid; //Current User UID

firebase.database().ref('Tables/Inmate_Data/'+userID).once('value').then(snapshot => {
    const userDOB = snapshot.val().Inmate_DOB;
    alert(userDOB);
});
```

To avoid getting null, you can put the above code inside `onAuthStateChanged`

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

    if(user) {
        var userID = user.uid;

        firebase.database().ref('Tables/Inmate_Data/'+userID).once('value').then(snapshot => {
            const userDOB = snapshot.val().Inmate_DOB;
            alert(userDOB);
        });
    }
});
```

If you want to retrieve the date of birth of all users, then you can do something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('Tables/Inmate_Data').on('child_added', snapshot => {
    firebase.database().ref(snapshot.key+'/Inmate_DOB').on('value', snap => {
        const userDOB = snap.val();
        alert(userDOB);
    });
});
```

Comment: I followed the same code which you have mentioned above, I'm having userId value, but I'm getting the DOB value as null.

Comment: @ShivSuthanM Did you try putting this code inside `onAuthStateChanged()`?

Comment: @ShivSuthanM I have updated my answer to include `onAuthStateChanged`

Comment: @ Chinmay Sarupria - I don't know what I missed in my code flow, Please check my full code in the updated question above. Still i didn't received the DOB. Console Log : Cannot read property 'Inmate_DOB'

Comment: @ShivSuthanM I just created a sample database like yours and the code is working for me, it is giving me the Inmate_DOB properly. I checked your code, you are missing a `;` on the line after `alert(test);`